# How to set the ZonedDateTime object to return a fixed time value while testing in Scala?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest

I'm using Scala WordSpec for writing unit test cases. While testing a method which returns the current time, I want to return a fixed time.

I want to mock `ZonedDateTime.now().getHour` method in my Code to return a fixed value for the purpose of testing.

I tried the code below but its not giving any results

```
 val mockZone = mock[ZonedDateTime]
    (mockZone.now("IN":"Asia/Kolkata").getHour)
      .expects()
      .returns(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following to get the `time`

```
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(java.util.Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toInstant))
```

and following to get the `date`

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(java.util.Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toInstant))
```

Hope it helps